# Want to show and hide wordpress page from google search engine

Tags: wordpress, search-engine

I have multiple pages on a daily base offers.

On offer expire I want that offer page to hide (or not show in google search engine) to other users. I Mean when user search my website for the page or offer in search engine then why should not show expired page link on the search result

Sometimes I also want to show that page when offer reopen

My website is on WordPress.

DO find a proper explanation :

We have a WordPress coupon, contest, and free samples websites. We post new offers every day. Those offers have an expiration date. This expiration date is a WordPress custom field. We would like to no-index from search engines all expired offers.

Sometimes we re-publish expired offers and they become available again. In this case, those offers should be re-indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will have to tell search engine to de-index your indexed pages & and you can follow these steps:

Go to the **GOOGLE WEBMASTER** then go with google index in that **Remove URL**.

Webmaster -> Google Index ->Remove URL -> Click on Temporary Hide

Follow the above steps and remove the URL from sites.

This way you can deindex your URL. If you need to cancel your 90-day block from search results, you can visit the status page of the tool and click Reinclude next to a successful request. Requests take a few days to be process.

Google has complete guide regarding this too >> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en